# Find norm of the following operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Find norm of the following bounded linear $Ax(t)=\int_0^1e^{ts}x(s)ds$ where $x\in C[0,1]$ and $t\in [0,1]$. Help me. Many thanks.

Comment: Firstly, start by estimating the norm. It should give you an idea what the norm is.

Comment: @Thanh Ha Nguyen: First, you need the definition of the operator norm. I know $3$ different (but equivalent) definition for the operator norm. Depending on which you have to use, the arguments can slightly differ. As user 1321324 wrote, the main idea is so estimate $\|A\|\leq c$ and $\|A\|\geq c$ such that you get $\|A\|=c$.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt The norm is supremum. I do not get your idea. Can you give me a detail answer? Many thanks

Comment: Find norm of the following bounded linear operator $Ax(t)=\int_0^1e^{ts}x(s)ds$, where $x\in C[0,1]$ and $t\in [0,1]$. Please help me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

DETAILED HINT: first you must show that $A$ is a **bounded** linear operator, that is, that map bounded sets to bounded sets, what is equivalent to say that $A$ is continuous.

Then the norm of $A$ exists and is defined as

$$\begin{align}\|A\|_{\mathcal L(C[0,1])}:&=\inf\{c\ge 0:\|Ax\|_\infty\le c\|x\|_\infty, x\in C[0,1]\}\\&=\inf\{c\ge 0:\|Ax\|_\infty\le c, \|x\|_\infty=1,x\in C[0,1]\}\\&=\sup\{\|Ax\|_\infty:\|x\|_\infty=1, x\in C[0,1]\}\end{align}$$

with $\|Ax\|_\infty=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|x(1)t^2|$.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your definition. I'm familiar with these three:
$$
\|A\|=\sup_{\stackrel{x\in C[0,1]}{\|x\|_\infty=1}}\|Ax\|_\infty
\\
\|A\|=\sup_{\stackrel{x\in C[0,1]}{\|x\|_\infty\leq1}}\|Ax\|_\infty
\\
\|A\|=\sup_{\stackrel{x\in C[0,1]}{\|x\|_\infty<1}}\|Ax\|_\infty
$$
Depending on the definition, you have to argue slightly different. I prefer to use the first (or second) one.

First, you have to find a constant $c$ such that $\|Ax\|_\infty\leq c$ for all $x\in C[0,1]$ with $\|x\|_\infty=1$, $\|x\|_\infty\leq 1$ or $\|x\|_\infty<1$ (depending on the definition...)
You have $$
\|Ax\|_\infty=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|x(1)t^2|=\ldots \leq \ldots
$$
You can compute the supremum directly and then estimate the value using $\|x\|_\infty=\sup_{s\in[0,1]}|x(s)|$.

This yields $\|A\|\leq c$.

Second, you have to prove $\|A\|\geq c$. Here you need an explicit function $\tilde{x}\in C[0,1]$ such that $\|\tilde x\|_\infty=1$ and $\|A\tilde x\|_\infty=c$. Then you deduce
$$
\|A\|=\sup_{\stackrel{x\in C[0,1]}{\|x\|_\infty=1}}\|Ax\|_\infty\geq \|A\tilde x\|_\infty =c.
$$
The function $\tilde x$ is not hard to find. Consider the first step, where you do the estimation. You can think of an (very simple) function, where equality holds. This function can be used in the second step.
**But** if you have to use the third definition from above, than you have to be careful in the second step, since you can use a function $\tilde x$ with $\|\tilde x\|_\infty=1$. Instead you have to define a sequence of functions $(\tilde x_n)_n$ where $\tilde x_n\in C[0,1]$, $\|\tilde x_n\|_\infty<1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \|A\tilde x_n\|_\infty=c$. Then you can say
$$
\|A\|=\sup_{\stackrel{x\in C[0,1]}{\|x\|_\infty<1}}\|Ax\|_\infty\geq \|A\tilde x_n\|_\infty
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb N$ hence
$$
\|A\|\geq \lim_{n\to\infty}\|A\tilde x_n\|_\infty=c.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The $C[0,1]$ norm is the sup (or max) norm of the continuous function on $[0,1]$.
$$
   \|Ax\|=\|x(1)t^2\|=|x(1)| \le \|x\|.
$$
So $A$ is bounded with $\|A\| \le 1$. The norm is $1$ because $\|A1\|=1=\|1\|$.