# Proof strategy for computing operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and consider a bounded operator $A:X\to \mathbb R$.

> I want to prove that $\|A\| = \alpha$ for a fixed $\alpha>0$ and I
>   already proved $\|A\|\leq \alpha$. So now ideally I would like to find
>   an $f$ such that $|Af| = \alpha$.

I didn't quite manage to do that but instead I found a sequence $(f_n)_n$ such that $\|f_n\|=1$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} |Af_n| = \alpha$. Is this sufficient to conclude the claim?

Comment: If you are trying to prove there exists $f\in X$ with $|Af|=\|a\|\cdot \|f\|\ne 0$ when $\|A\|\ne 0,$ then don't. There are counter-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, assuming that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ lies in the unit ball though.

Comment: Each of the $f_n$ has norm $1$. How do we conclude the claim formally?

Comment: $\|A\| = \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|Ax\| \geq \lim_{n\to\infty}\|Af_n\| = \alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't quite manage to do that but instead I found a sequence $(f_n)_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|Af_n|=\alpha$. Is this sufficient to conclude the claim?

To be precise, we need the definition of your operator norm!
See my answer [>here<](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540839/find-norm-of-the-following-operator/2541012#2541012), where I gave three common (and equivalent) definitions of the operator norm. For the first case, you need $|f_n|=1$, for the second $|f_n|\leq 1$ and for the third $|f_n|<1$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. If you have this, then elemental analysis yields:

*If $(a_n)_n$ is a convergent sequence in $\mathbb R$, $s,S\in \mathbb R$ and $a\leq a_n\leq S$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, then $s\leq \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\leq S$.*

In your case: If $|Af_n|\leq \|A\|$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} |Af_n|\leq \|A\|$ .